# How can get this function to exclude certain values?

Tags: sql

So pretty much I am trying to get this SQL statement to work,

I need to find a list of artist names, the number of CDs by that
artist and the average price for their CDs but not including
‘Electronica’ albums.

So far I have got the first bit working, I can return the list of artist names, the number of CDs and the Average price, but i cannot get it to succesfully exclude the Electronica albums, and was wondering if there was a simple way of doing so?

My code that I have attempted to finish is:

```
SELECT Artist.artName, AVG(CD.cdPrice), Count(*) 
FROM CD 
INNER JOIN Artist 
ON Artist.artID=CD.artID 
Group by Artist.artID 
Having count(*) >1
WHERE Artist.artID =
CD.artID AND artGenre
NOT LIKE “Electronica”));
```

Comment: In which table is `artGenre` a column?

Comment: The Artist table, Sorry i didn't make that clear.

Comment: Does the `artGenre` field contain the word you're trying to exclude on or start with it or end with it? You probably want to use `%` signs  in your `LIKE` unless it simply contains only the word you are excluding on. But if that was the case you could just use equals instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: the artGenre Field contains the whole word "Electronica" whenever it encounters that word i want it to exclude that value from the outputted table, currently it just prints an empty error message and does nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cleaned up your query a bit:

```
SELECT Artist.artName, AVG(CD.cdPrice), Count(*)
FROM CD INNER JOIN Artist
ON Artist.artID=CD.artID
WHERE Artist.artGenre NOT LIKE "%Electronica%"
GROUP BY Artist.artID
```

In your original query you had `WHERE Artist.artID = CD.artID`, which is totally unnecessary since you already specified this in the `JOIN`.  Also I removed the `HAVING count(*) > 1` clause since it was not part of the original problem statement.

Comment: Bonus points: Can you explain what was wrong with your original query?